# How to fix 'MySQL Error: 1822. Missing index for contraint' On creating a composite foreign key

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a table with a composite foreign key, but keep getting met with the error `Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_multiple' in the referenced table 'contractdates'`

I'm using `MySQL v8.0.16`

I've checked if the column types are different, and I'm not sure what else could be the problem.

Here are the tables that make up the problem, All tables are made happily but the last one that contains the composite key causes the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE `contracts` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompletionDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `fieldheading` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldTypeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldHeading` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `contractdates` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateValue` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContractID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FieldHeadingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq_contractdates_contractID_FieldHeading_ID` (`ContractID`,`FieldHeadingID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdates_contracts_id_idx` (`ContractID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdates_fieldheading_id_idx` (`FieldHeadingID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdates_fieldheading_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FieldHeadingID`) REFERENCES `fieldheading` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdates_contracts_id` FOREIGN KEY (`ContractID`) REFERENCES `contracts` (`id`)
) COMMENT='Table to hold the dates for a contract, one row is one date for a specific contract';

CREATE TABLE `contractdateshistoric` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ContractID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ContractDateCurrentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FieldHeadingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChangedByID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateValue` datetime NOT NULL,
  `TimeStampChanged` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_mutiple_idx` (`ContractID`, `FieldHeadingID`, `ContractDateCurrentID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_multiple` FOREIGN KEY (`ContractID`, `FieldHeadingID`, `ContractDateCurrentID`) REFERENCES `contractdates` (`contractid`, `fieldheadingid`, `id`)
) COMMENT='Audit trail of the dates';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Composite FK in the table `contractdates` try adding composite index as well

```
  KEY `fk_contractdates_mutiple_idx` (`ContractID`,`FieldHeadingID`,`ID`)
```

Whole create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `contractdates` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DateValue` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContractID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FieldHeadingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdates_contracts_id_idx` (`ContractID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdates_fieldheading_id_idx` (`FieldHeadingID`),
  KEY `fk_contractdates_mutiple_idx` (`ContractID`,`FieldHeadingID`,`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdates_fieldheading_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FieldHeadingID`) REFERENCES `fieldheading` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdates_contracts_id` FOREIGN KEY (`ContractID`) REFERENCES `contracts` (`id`)
) COMMENT='Table to hold the dates for a contract, one row is one date for a specific contract';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to tell you *"you haven't created a necessary unique index on contractdates, that covers the columns (contractid, fieldheadingid, id) so I cannot create a foreign key on contractdateshistoric that refers to this set of columns when determining the single parent row"*

I'm not sure why you're creating an fk that references 3 columns when contractdates has a pk that is just the ID column.

If a contractdateshistoric records refers to a single contractdates record as its parent, the historic record should have a contractdateid column that refers to contractdates.id - no need for multiple columns. Copy the pattern you used to relate a contractdates to its parent contract, and you'll be fine

Comment: I created a fk that references 3 columns as I want the ability to join `contractdateshistoric` without having to join to `contractdates`. The `contractid` and `fieldheadingid` is essential for this. If I were to only have `contractdateid` as a foreign key that means I can have a historicdate that links to an existing `contractdateid` but contains non existing `contractid` or `fieldheadingid` or a combination that doesn't exist in `contractdates`. Maybe I could omit `contractdatesid` but that would still pose the multiple foreign key problem. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, the combination of fieldheadingid and contractid should be `UNIQUE` in `contractdates` but not in `contractdateshistoric`, I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Erm.. Surely `contractdateshistoric`, being just a history table that is automatically maintained (by a trigger?) will not need this FK, because it will only ever contain values that have had a valid contractid/fieldheadingid. You don't need to FK the history table because it only gets its data from a table that is already FK'd. You cannot change the ContractDates table to have a FieldHeadingId that does not exist, hence the history table cannot either have bad data in it.. If you want to join the history tabl that's nothing to do with an FK. Tables can be joined even if they have no FKs

Comment: But all that said, contractdateshistoric should not have an FK to contractdates, because it is not a child table of contractdates, it is a sibling table and hence has the same rules for its entries, it should have FKs to contract and fieldheading if you really insist (but it's not necessary and probably will trip you up at some point

Comment: You are correct about the trigger part, I think I am just overthinking things as this is a part of one of my first designs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by creating the keys individually for the columns, Please find the updated query:

```
CREATE TABLE `contractdateshistoric` (
    `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ContractID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ContractDateCurrentID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `FieldHeadingID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ChangedByID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `DateValue` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `TimeStampChanged` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_mutiple_idx` (`ContractID`),
    KEY `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_mutiple_idx1` (`FieldHeadingID`),
    KEY `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_mutiple_idx2` (`ContractDateCurrentID`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_multiple` FOREIGN KEY (`ContractID`)
    REFERENCES `contractdates` (`contractid`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_multiple1` FOREIGN KEY (`FieldHeadingID`)
    REFERENCES `contractdates` (`fieldheadingid`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_contractdateshistoric_contractdates_multiple2` FOREIGN KEY (`ContractDateCurrentID`)
    REFERENCES `contractdates` (`id`)
);
```

It works fine.

Comment: The OP is saying **composite index** is not working.